# How to setState(data) when the data is received after user clicked a button

Tags: asynchronous, fetch, setstate

I'm new to React and am trying to fetch something when user clicked the submit button → then set the data I received by `setBox(data)`.

```
 const [box, setBox] = useState([])

    onSubmit = () => {
       
        fetch(theUrlIWant)
          .then(resp => resp.json())
          .then(data => {
              setBox(data);
            console.log(box);
            })
          .catch(err => console.log(err);
          );
    }
```

I understand that setState is not synchronous, but I really need the data to be set once the fetch success. After the fetch success, I want to pass the `box` to a child component as a prop.

No matter how I tried, the first click would always print out nothing (an empty array). The second click would make everything fine.
How do I fix this issue?

If the code I provide are not enough to debug, kindly let me know
please see the code line 52
[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-surf-r7g9h?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: can u plz create a code sandbox

Comment: I'd like to provide one but the code inside require a private api key, how should I avoid that yet provide a well functional code snippet?

Comment: just fetch data from data.json file.... just want to see your code to debug it

Comment: I've added a CodeSandBox to the question, please take a look, thank you!

Comment: setState is async function and you are setting it in onSubmit function and just after getting its value in the same function, due to async its value is not updated

Comment: yes I understand that, there should be some ways I could get the data immediately..?

Comment: you are calling this function setImageUrl(() => input); so you have the value in Input variable

Comment: so you can use input variable directly in API

Comment: The data I want is actually the data I tried to fetch, but I couldn't get it, the request responded 400. Let alone the following code displayFaceBox(data).

Comment: let response = await app.models.predict(
        Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL,
        `${input}`
      );

Comment: Thank you so much... I was so clumsy and missed that point.

Comment: no problem, enjoy codding